# How to populate a custom list with two arrays.

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, getter-setter

I created a custom adapter class and a getter and setter class called Bean. This is to make a list view that has a textView and an image.

How can I populate myList so that it is usable when i'm setting the adapter and thus displays the corresponding text and image from my arrays into my listView?

I have provided the code for my adapter and bean class as well as my Main Activity Class' Async Task , but the problem is in my onPostExecute method from my Async class.

***Just To Clarify. This code has NOT been tested and therefore has not returned any errors. My question is how do I populate myList in the onPostExecute method with the information from the String arrays "descriptionArray" and "photoArray".***

My Main Activity Class' Async Task

```
    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String content = HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
        return content;
    }




//-----------------------THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS HAPPENING---------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        hideDialog();
        String parseResult = InfoJSONResultParser.parseFeed(result);

        importerArray = OrderInformationParser.orderParser(result);

        if (parseResult.equals("ok")) {
            //Returns the Array with the JSON info already parsed.
            List<Bean> myList = new ArrayList<>(); //<---***How to populate this***




//***With  the information from these two String arrays.***
            String[] descriptionArray = OrderInformationParser.orderParser(result);
            String[] photoArray = PhotoParser.photoParser(result);


            //This creates and executes the list
            list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.orderListView);


            //***So i can then transfer over to this adapter***
            MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, myList);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);


        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.nullOrders).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

}
```

Adapter Class

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private List<Bean> mList;

public MyAdapter(Context context,List<Bean> list){
    mContext=context;
    mList=list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    //use converview recycle
    if(convertView==null){
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.content_orders, parent, false);
        holder.textView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.imageView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //set text and url
    holder.textView.setText(mList.get(position).getText());
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(mList.get(position).getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder{
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;

}
}
```

Bean Class

```
public class Bean {
String text;
String url;

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Does it throw an exception? Please be more specific on your issue

Comment: @rsella It's not throwing an exception. I simply don't know how to populate myList<Bean> with the information from the String arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can populate your List by iterating your 2 Arrays and add the Strings to the Bean Objects.

Example:

```
 private List<Bean> populateBeanList(List<Bean> myList, String[] descArray, String[] photoArray){

     for(int i=0; i< descArray.length; i++){

      Bean bean = new Bean();
      bean.setText(descArray[i]);
      bean.setUrl(photoArray[i]);
      myList.Add(bean);
     }

   return myList;
}
```

Then call the function in your Async Class

```
    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String content = HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
        return content;
    }




//-----------------------THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS HAPPENING---------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        hideDialog();
        String parseResult = InfoJSONResultParser.parseFeed(result);

        importerArray = OrderInformationParser.orderParser(result);

        if (parseResult.equals("ok")) {
            //Returns the Array with the JSON info already parsed.
            List<Bean> myList = new ArrayList<>(); //<---***How to populate this***




//***With  the information from these two String arrays.***
            String[] descriptionArray = OrderInformationParser.orderParser(result);
            String[] photoArray = PhotoParser.photoParser(result);

        myList = populateBeanList(myList,descriptionArray, photoArray);

        //This creates and executes the list
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.orderListView);


        //***So i can then transfer over to this adapter***
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, myList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


    } else {
        findViewById(R.id.nullOrders).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

}

Update:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private List<Bean> mList;
private static LayoutInflater inflater;

public MyAdapter(Activity act,List<Bean> list){
    activity=act;
    mList=list;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    //use converview recycle
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_orders, null);
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.imageView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //set text and url
    holder.textView.setText(mList.get(position).getText());
    Picasso.with(activity).load(mList.get(position).getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);

    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder{
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;

}
}
```

Comment: Although the best way to populate the list would be to serialize the Web response into a List<Bean> using ie: GSON, Jackson.

Comment: This is exactly what i ended up doing and it worked using the text portion so thank you! I assume i must be doing something wrong in my adapter class because my image still isn't displaying. Only the text View.

Comment: Did you figure out what's going on with your Adapter?

Comment: I have not. I've been working at it for a while now but even using the debugger it's hard to figure out exactly what's going on. I'm positive it's in the adapter. I might have to stray away from Picasso...perhaps that's just not the best thing to use with a listview.

Comment: I figured it out! It was not even in my adapter, it was a silly mistake in how i was setting up my image urls. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood of your issue, you don't know how to populate the list.

Well, that's an easy task. Let's assume that `descriptionArray` contains the texts and `photoArray` contains the urls.

The needed code is that:

First, **add a constructor** to the `Bean` class for convenience:

```
public Bean(String text, String url) {
    this.text = text;
    this.url = url;
}
```

It simply add a non-empty constructor so we can initialize class fields directly on instance creation.

Second, **call the method `add`** of `ArrayList`. Like this:

```
myList.add(new Bean(text, url))
```

Obviously you need to put it in a for loop (for every item of arrays you insert a new `Bean`). So it will be like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<descriptionArray.lenght; i++) {
    myList.add(new Bean(descriptionArray[i], photoArray[i]);
}
```

This will create a new `Bean` for every pair in `descriptionArray` and `photoArray`.

As such, you'll need to check if the two arrays have the same size. 
For doing this you must put the `for` loop in an if:

```
if (descriptionArray.lenght == photoArray.lenght) {
    //execute for loop
}
else {
    //Arrays have different size. Wtf? Manage the error
}
```

Maybe time do a little Google research on the topic before posting ;)

Hope it helps a little